# Recheck the URL thrice for web exception cases powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$status_wait =1    
Do{
  $https_request= invoke_webrequest -uri "https:\\"
  $https_status = [int]http_request.statuscode

  If($($_.categoryinfo.reason) -eq "webexception") {
    Start-sleep -secounds 30
    $status_wait+=1
  }
  Elseif($http_status -eq 200) {
    Write-host "URL is up"
  }
}Untill (status_wait -eq 3)
```

Comment: I am looking for , rechecking the URL thrice before going to restart the services in the server. When the URL is showing web exception it's not checking thrice , I want to check the URL thrice when it is down .pls help me

Comment: Please edit the _question_ and add problem description there too. As of now, understanding the problem requires reading comment section too. Comments are [not a discussion thread](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), but kind of Post-It notes for small observations.

Comment: Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something like this ?

```
#Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$url = "www.yourtargetsite.com"
    
function try-webrequest($url){
    try{
        return (Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -ErrorAction Stop)
    }catch{
        return $_
    }
}
    
$wr = try-webrequest $url
    
if ($wr.statuscode -ne 200){        
    If($wr.categoryinfo.reason -eq "webexception"){
        $count = 1
        while($count -lt 4){
            "Retrying...$count"
            $count++
            if ((try-webrequest $url).statuscode -eq 200){break}
            sleep -seconds 30 
        }
    }else{
        #In case you want to handle any other exception
        "The link is down NOT due to webexception"
    }
}else{
    "The link's up"
}
```

PS: I have just started answering on stackoverflow. I'd love to hear your feedback.

Comment: A good rule of thumb for SO, if you see an off-topic question that you feel wouldn't meet SO guidelines, even if you know how to answer it, restrain yourself and just flag them. If we answer off-topic questions, it encourages bad behavior in SO which wasn't intended from the creation of SO. For some good articles about these guidlines, see [What shouldn't I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What can I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also check out , the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)